# How to implement GetEnumerator method in update panel?

Tags: c#, updatepanel

I want to iterate through various controls of update panel. While iterating using ID for control I want to delete some of the controls.

But I don't know how to iterate through controls of update panel using `GetEnumerator` method?
If we can do iteration by some other way, please let me know.

Comment: Look at my post where I say that the controls can be nested if they are located on a Panel.. so the bottom one only assumes it will find controls on myUpdatePanel.. what if there were other controls of that type not on myUpdatePanel but inside a div or something for example.. ???

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you loop over the Controls collection of the updatepanel:

```
 foreach(var control in myUpdatePanel.Controls) {
      ...
 }
```

Comment: You did not account for nested controls inside of a Panel or Panels

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the ControlCollection.

Just remember that these controls can be nested, if they are in panels eg.

```
private void RecusiceControls(ControlCollection controls)
        {
            foreach (Control control in controls)
            {
                RecusiceControls((ControlCollection)control.Controls);
                if (control is Button) // whatever the control is you are looking for
                {
                }
            }
        }
```